# ClearContents for constants but not formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a range (N1:N12) on a sheet1 and I've got a code that copy and paste me the values of that range on a secondary sheet2. Everything is working, anyway i didn't consider that i want another button that clear only values in range N1:N12 once i have copied them in sheet2. I don't know how to keep formulas on that range when i want to delete values. Do you have an idea ? I've already tried a normal macro that deletes everything but it is not what i want.

```
Sub Cancella() 
    Sheets("Foglio1").select 
    Range("N1:N12").clearcontents
End Sub
```

The code i use for copying

```
Dim lastRow As Long
    Sheets("Training Analysis").Range("P1:R13").Copy

    lastRow = Sheets("Foglio1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Foglio1").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little?  You want to clear the cells `N1:N12`, after copying to `Sheet2`?  Can you post the other code you have too?  Or do you want to clear range `N1:N12` but keep the formulas in `N1:N12` (if so, can you clarify what you mean by that??)

Comment: yes i wan to clear cells N1:N12 after copying to sheet2. This is my code i use to copy {Dim lastRow As Long
Sheets("Training Analysis").Range("P1:R13").Copy

lastRow = Sheets("Foglio1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Foglio1").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True'}

Comment: (Can you instead add that code to your OP, and mark as code with the `{}` tags?)

Comment: Yes sorry about that. Above you can find my code that i use for copying, it refers to different cells, but i just need how the mechanism is working.

Comment: No because when i click clear contents it clears all, even the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Range("N1:N12").clearcontents
```

with:

```
For i = 1 To 12
   If Not Cells(i, "N").HasFormula Then Cells(i, "N").ClearContents
Next i
```

Comment: What was he trying to do? Clear only cells without a formula? I couldn't quite make out his question.

Comment: @BruceWayne  I assumed he/she wanted to retain formulas.

Comment: Yes i've tried to run this code but it does not delete the values neither the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subset of the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) that targets [xlCellTypeConstants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx). This can be further broken down to xlNumbers, xlTextValues, xlErrors , xlLogical or a combination of same.

```
With WorkSheets("Foglio1")
    .Range("N1:N12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).ClearContents
End With
```

Conversely, cells containing formulas can be similarly targeted with the [xlCellTypeFormulas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) subset.

Comment: With this code i got an error saying that it cannot find cells.

Comment: The code has been tested and works assuming that you have typed numbers in the N1:N12 range on the **Foglio1** worksheet. Kind of hard to offer anything more without seeing some sample data.

Comment: I got numbers in that range but when i run the macro it gives me a run time error '1004'.